# How to close a print window in a browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to close print window of a browser using java script or any other method, java script is more preferable. If you possible close the print window for IE ,Chrome and Safari will be grateful.

pls help..

thanks guys.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent people from printing something? If so, give up.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a window, it's a dialog and it is controlled by the operating system, not JavaScript.  ie. You cannot control it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot close the print dialog via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with all browser dialog (close, valid, etc). So you can't close the window like this.
I think, the best way is understand why you want to close it ?

- you want block user to print ? i have already see users make print
  screen and print via paint (really !).
- the dialog is automaticaly opened ? So, you need to know why/what
  open it and block it.

More informations to solved your problem are required.